# wordpress php code widget show an error message on debugging mode true

Tags: wordpress

i integrate php widget in maxmenu configuration panel widget to make my menu dynamic
but when i do wp_debug mode true it show an error message before every post, that is:

```
undefined variable eval()'d code on line 9
```

inside php file of php widget

my code inside php widget is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <?php query_posts('cat=11&posts_per_page=5');?>
        <?php if(have_posts()): 
       while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'menu-thumb'); 
     $item = '<div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="mega_single">
        <a href="'.get_permalink().'">
        <img src="'.$img[0].'" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        <article>'.get_the_title().'</article>
        </a>
      </div><!--mega single-->
     </div>';
     echo $item;
     endwhile; endif;?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Donnow about the error, but [don't use query_posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)...

Comment: hello brasofilo, thanks for support what should i use instead of query post can u please describe i am new in wordpress.